# PHP pagination unordered list item

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm getting an array value from external source and I'm converting it to into unordered list to display on webpage. But sometime contents of the list are very large to display on the single page. Is it possible to paginate the content so that it can show 10 list item per page.

```
   <div id="a">
      <div id="object3">TRIVIA</div>
      <div class="details">
        <?php foreach ($tri as $key): echo "<ul><li>$key</li></ul>"; endforeach ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: although you wouldnt have the <ul></ul> in the foreach, they would be outside - and you would just display the individual list items.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it requires actually writing a paginator.

You will need, however, to be able to get a count, and be able to display a range of results based on a url string like ?start=10&end=20.

The rest is simply using either a for loop or a foreach with a `(if(count<start)continue;)` and `(if(count>end)break;)`

You also need to generate links to go forward and back at the very least, and to not generate a link if you are at the start or end of the total count.

Answer (score 0):

The only piece of information you need to pass in to your script is the page number, since that is the only thing that changes between pages.

There are other bits of information you need to know, such as `numberPerPage`, but they are included in your script and never change.

Here is a MySQL statement that will get you started:

```
SELECT columnList
FROM table
ORDER BY someColumn
LIMIT 10,5
```

The LIMIT clause says skip the first 10 records, then give me the next 5.  This is the foundation and starting point for all pagination scripts that utilize a MySQL backend.

**So how do you know the offset?**

By that external piece of information I mentioned earlier, the current page number, combined with the internal piece of information I also mentioned earlier, the number per page.

If you are wanting to view page 5 and you intend to show 10 elements per page, then it is pretty easy to see that you want to start at row #41:

- Page 1 showed elements 1-10
- Page 2 showed elements 11-20
- Page 3 showed elements 21-30
- Page 4 showed elements 31-40
- Page 5 needs to show elements 41-50

You can calculate the offset then this way:

```
$offset = $numPerPage * ($curPage - 1)
```

On Page 1, the offset will be 0 (which is what you want).

On Page 2, the offset will be 10, and so on.

[Here](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination) is a link to a more thorough tutorial on pagination.

Answer (score 0):

PEAR's [Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) package has been made for this task. See the [examples](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.pager.intro.php).